# simulate.p.value option in chisq.test in R

Tags: r, chi-squared-test

I have the low expected values problem in my data set and cannot solve with regular methods (e.g. combining levels, etc). I cannot use Fisher's test either because of the fixed marginals assumption of the Fisher's test.

I want to try the permutation test in the `chisq.test` function in R (that is  `simulate.p.value` option in `chisq.test`). However, **I would like to know whether this simulation assumes fixed marginals in the data or not?** (My data is not suitable for fixed marginals assumption, marginals may change depending on the sample taken.)

Comment: As the linked duplicate indicates, it uses Patefield's algorithm which samples tables conditional on the margins. That it conditions on the margins is quite explicit in the help: "*In the contingency table case simulation is done by random sampling from the set of all contingency tables with given marginals,*"; however the fact that your margins are not fixed may be largely beside the point (both for this case and FIsher's exact test); the conditioning is not an assumption about your sampling situation, but relates to inference while conditioning on (almost) ancillary marginal totals... ctd

Comment: ctd... see the discussion of the debate about conditionality [here](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4388855/), or see wikipedia [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%27s_exact_test#Controversies).